# Как определить второй видимый элемент у jcarousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jcarousel

Доброго вечера, ситуация немного бедовая, вынужден использовать только одну карусель jcarousel, у блоке контейнера стоит свойство overflow:hidden; мне нужно выделить второй видимый элемент... 
есть ли какой нибудь не сложный способ это сделать...
jQuery(".front_page .jcarousel-skin-island").jcarousel({
                auto: 0,
                scroll: 1,
                visible: 3,
                wrap: 'circular',
                buttonNextHTML:'',
                buttonPrevHTML:'',
            }); 
должно быть как тут: http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/  слайдер "Center Mode"

Comment: ну так и код предоставьте сюда.

Comment: Меня интересует, можно ли как-то узнать сколько видимых элементов у блоке со свойством overflow:hidde...

Comment: можно, всё можно узнать.

Comment: подскажите пожалуйста как...